# Install a specific Torch version

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, torch

I am trying to install an specfic old version of torch

I took this snippet from [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#linux-and-windows-10)

```
conda install pytorch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 torchaudio==0.8.0 cpuonly -c pytorch
```

When I do

```
import torch
```

I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Are you using a custom anaconda environment?

Comment: I am using a custom anaconda environment in GCP jupyter notebook

Comment: Have you checked that PyTorch is installed in the correct environment? Try running `!conda list pytorch` in a notebook cell